# httpclient throw exception on redirect

Tags: c#, redirect, web-scraping, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to download a webpage with HttpClient, that's my code:

```
private async Task<string> _doRequest(string url)
{
  string result = string.Empty;

  var client = HttpClient;
  using(var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
  {
    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
    Method = HttpMethod.Get
  }){
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
      if (response.Headers.Location == null)
      {
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
          result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
      }
      else
      {
        result = await _doRequest(response.Headers.Location.ToString());
      }
  };

  return result;
}
```

HttpClient is a static variable initialized as follow:

```
  var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
  handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
  handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
  HttpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
  HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36");
```

When I try to execute the code with url = `"https://www.gls-italy.com/?option=com_gls&view=track_e_trace&mode=search&numero_spedizione=TE170187747&tipo_codice=nazionale"`

I get the following:
[image]

Which is what lead me to try with curl:
[image]

And here I am lost. To me it looks like a valid 302 with location, but for some reasons HttpClient believe otherwise and just throw an exception.

To be clear initially I was relying on AllowAutoRedirect default value and thrust HttpClient to do the redirect, it didn't work, I was getting this same exception which lead me to try to manage it myself. But with no success.

Anyone knows what's happening? How to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not the HttpClient. I've tried your link with HttpWebRequest, but a WebException.SendFailure arises. This is a bad 302 response. The connection is closed. The Location states that the new address is `https://wwwdr.`(...). If you change `www` with `wwwdr` the server aswers correctly.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but a heads-up that you want to avoid using `.Result` in async methods. It can result in deadlocks. If you await client.SendAsync(request), you'll get the result unpacked, avoid a deadlock scenario and potentially get more usage out of your thread.

Comment: @Jimi I know if I request wwwdr it's working bu they could change that, I need a way to follow the redirect, curl does follow the redirect there must be a way to manage it from c# as well.

Comment: @ You probably haven't explicitly set the protocol to TLS 1.2. This server uses only that. So set `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` before the HttpRequest is created.

Comment: @Jimi I tried that earlier doesn't change the result, which make sense because I am on net 4.6.2. I think the problem is the connection: close in the response. There must be a way of reading the response with HttpClient even with connection: close...

Comment: @Max Favilli  I've tried it now with fw 4.7.1 and the server answers as expected, using HttpWebRequest. Can't test 4.6.2. We discarded this release.

Comment: @Max Favilli It works with fw 4.5.1

Comment: @Max Favilli  Tested with `HttpClient.SendAsync()` with both fw 4.5.1 and fw 4.7.1. Working if `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`.

Comment: @Max Favilli  I'm posting here what I've used, in case you haven't solved your problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Objects at Class level:

```
HttpClientHandler Http_Handler = new HttpClientHandler();
HttpClient Http_Client = new HttpClient();
CookieContainer HttpClCookieJar = new CookieContainer();
```

HttpClient setup stub:

```
private void HttpClient_Setup()
{
   Http_Handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
   Http_Handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
   Http_Handler.CookieContainer = HttpClCookieJar;
   Http_Handler.UseCookies = true;
   Http_Handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
   Http_Client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(30000);
   Http_Client = new HttpClient(Http_Handler);
   Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0");
   Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
   Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
   Http_Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
}
```

Async HttpClient request:

```
public async Task<string> HttpClient_Request(string RequestURL)
{
   string _responseHtml = string.Empty;
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | 
                                          SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
                                          SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
   try
   {
      using (HttpRequestMessage _requestMsg = new HttpRequestMessage())
      {
         _requestMsg.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
         _requestMsg.RequestUri = new Uri(RequestURL);

         using (HttpResponseMessage _response = await Http_Client.SendAsync(_requestMsg))
         {
            using (HttpContent _content = _response.Content)
            {
               _responseHtml = await _content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            };
         };
      };
   }
   catch (HttpRequestException eW)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Message: {}  Source: {1}", eW.Message, eW.Source);
   }
   catch (Exception eX)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Message: {}  Source: {1}", eX.Message, eX.Source);
   }
   return _responseHtml;
}
```